# How to reduce the if statement for multiple arguments?

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to reduce this code:

```
carro$custo_tprivate = with(carro, ifelse(decile_renda == 1, 
renda_fa*0.116,
ifelse(decile_renda == 2, renda_fa*0.106,
ifelse(decile_renda == 3, renda_fa*0.102,
ifelse(decile_renda == 4, renda_fa*0.115,
ifelse(decile_renda == 5, renda_fa*0.124,
ifelse(decile_renda == 6, renda_fa*0.125,
ifelse(decile_renda == 7, renda_fa*0.137,
ifelse(decile_renda == 8, renda_fa*0.141,
ifelse(decile_renda == 9, renda_fa*0.156,
ifelse(decile_renda == 10, renda_fa*0.131, 0)))))))))))
```

Someone could teach me how to do that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd use `dplyr::mutate()` with `dplyr::case_when()`. [Examples in the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when).

Answer (score 0):

You can technically use match statement to reduce your ifelse statements as below

```
# put your case data into a data frame
data = data.frame(x= seq(1, 10, by = 1)
           , y = runif(10))

# creating your actual data
carro = data.frame(decile_renda = sample(1:10, 10, replace =T)
                   ,renda_fa = runif(10)
                   )

#Match it to get positions of case statement
pos = with(carro, match(decile_renda, data$x, 0))     

# multiply to get results
data$y[pos]*carro$renda_fa
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Not_Dave.
I will try :-)

You really help me a lot. All of you are great.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this can be solved by left-joining with a lookup table.

If I understand correctly the nested `ifelse()` construct, the OP wants to multiply `renda` with a factor which depends on the value of `decile_renda`. The factors are given for 10 distinct values of `decile_renda`. In all other cases, the result must be zero.

Using left join will find matching values of `decile_renda` in the lookup table. Non-matching rows in `carro` will get an `NA` value. These need to be replaced by zero, subsequently.

The lookup table treats the single use cases as data instead of hard-coding. This gives the flexibility to add or change the use cases without changing the code.

#### Create lookup table and test dataset

```
# create lookup table
lut <- data.frame(
  decile_renda = 1:10,
  fa = c(0.116, 0.106, 0.102, 0.115, 0.124, 0.125, 0.137, 0.141, 0.156, 0.131)
)
lut
```

> ```
>    decile_renda    fa
> 1             1 0.116
> 2             2 0.106
> 3             3 0.102
> 4             4 0.115
> 5             5 0.124
> 6             6 0.125
> 7             7 0.137
> 8             8 0.141
> 9             9 0.156
> 10           10 0.131
> ```

```
# create test dataset
carro <- data.frame(decile_renda = 0:11, renda_fa = 100)
# randomize row order
set.seed(1L) # required for reproducible data
carro <- carro[sample(nrow(carro)), ]
carro
```

> ```
>    decile_renda renda_fa
> 9             8      100
> 4             3      100
> 7             6      100
> 1             0      100
> 2             1      100
> 5             4      100
> 3             2      100
> 8             7      100
> 6             5      100
> 11           10      100
> 12           11      100
> 10            9      100
> ```

Note that the test dataset has been choosen to allow for easy verification of the results.

#### Base R: `merge()`

```
carro <- merge(carro, lut, all.x = TRUE, by = "decile_renda")
carro$custo_tprivate <- with(carro, ifelse(is.na(fa), 0, renda_fa * fa))
carro
```

> ```
>    decile_renda renda_fa    fa custo_tprivate
> 1             0      100    NA            0.0
> 2             1      100 0.116           11.6
> 3             2      100 0.106           10.6
> 4             3      100 0.102           10.2
> 5             4      100 0.115           11.5
> 6             5      100 0.124           12.4
> 7             6      100 0.125           12.5
> 8             7      100 0.137           13.7
> 9             8      100 0.141           14.1
> 10            9      100 0.156           15.6
> 11           10      100 0.131           13.1
> 12           11      100    NA            0.0
> ```

Note that the result column `custo_tprivate` shows `0.0` for the rows with non-matching `decile_renda` values of `0` and `11` as requested.

However, the drawback here is that `merge()` does not maintain the original row order (this is why the test dataset uses a random row order for demonstration). Also, the result contains the `fa` column which is no longer needed.

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
carro %>% 
  left_join(lut, by = "decile_renda") %>% 
  mutate(custo_tprivate = if_else(is.na(fa), 0, renda_fa * fa)) %>% 
  select(-fa)
```

> ```
>    decile_renda renda_fa custo_tprivate
> 1             8      100           14.1
> 2             3      100           10.2
> 3             6      100           12.5
> 4             0      100            0.0
> 5             1      100           11.6
> 6             4      100           11.5
> 7             2      100           10.6
> 8             7      100           13.7
> 9             5      100           12.4
> 10           10      100           13.1
> 11           11      100            0.0
> 12            9      100           15.6
> ```

Here, the original row order is kept and the `fa` column has been removed.

#### data.table

With `data.table` we can do an *update join* where the matching rows of `carro` are being updated by reference, i.e., without copying the whole object. Only the result column `custo_tprivate` is appended to `carro` but not `fa` which would have to be removed afterwards. Also, for replacing the `NA` values only the affected rows are updated in place.

This might be an advantage in terms of speed and memory consumption in case of large datasets.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(carro)[lut, on = .(decile_renda), custo_tprivate := renda_fa * fa]
carro[is.na(custo_tprivate), custo_tprivate := 0]
carro
```

> ```
>     decile_renda renda_fa custo_tprivate
>  1:            8      100           14.1
>  2:            3      100           10.2
>  3:            6      100           12.5
>  4:            0      100            0.0
>  5:            1      100           11.6
>  6:            4      100           11.5
>  7:            2      100           10.6
>  8:            7      100           13.7
>  9:            5      100           12.4
> 10:           10      100           13.1
> 11:           11      100            0.0
> 12:            9      100           15.6
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution really makes sense. Much easier.

I sent my schoolwork last Friday, but I will apply this solution now, just to check and improve the script.

Thank you again.